# compare two files get identical list

Tags: sed, awk, grep, join

file1.txt (50 lines)

```
TERYUFV00000010753
TERYUFV00000009526
```

file2.txt (500 lines)

```
TERYUFV00000009526 refids_739_known_8/10_target
TERYUFV00000018907 refids_12023_known_21/22_target
TERYUFV00000010753 refids_11775_known_1/1_target
```

Output.txt

```
TERYUFV00000010753 refids_11775_known_1/1_target
TERYUFV00000009526 refids_739_known_8/10_target
```

Compare file1.txt (has 50 lines) with file2.txt (has 500 lines), get the list from file2.txt which are identical to file1.txt.

I tried both join & fgrep command and it outputs empty file

Comment: Similar question [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47492/what-is-the-best-way-to-find-a-list-of-several-strings-within-a-large-text-file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fgrep -f file1.txt file2.txt`

Here we are obtaining search pattern from file1.txt and searching it in file2.txt.
As the text is fixed we are using `fgrep` for faster search operation.

[image]

Comment: as the file1 has 50 lines and file2 has 500 lines..this is not working

Comment: It should work as per your description i.e. *get the list from file2.txt which are identical to file1.txt*

Comment: strange.it doesnt give any output for me..

Comment: Don't know why it is not working for you. I just uploaded a screenshot of my terminal where you can see the required output. Is it giving any error when you execute the command?

Comment: it outputs empty file

Comment: The screenshot is illegible on my computer, because the whole screen was resized to a small area. Maybe it should be trimmed to only display the information on the top-left corner.

Comment: According to the exact wording of the original question, you need to add the `-x` option, otherwise matches of only part of a line will be permitted.  Although I see the OP's actual use case doesn't match the question he asked.

Answer (score 4):

When you use join the entries on each line are like "cells" in a db, but they should be sorted, so you can try,

```
sort file1.txt > file1_t.txt
sort file2.txt > file2_t.txt
```

And then do the join

```
$ join file1_t.txt file2_t.txt
```

which will give you an external join, i.e. a list of all the occurrences of the cells in both files. To reduce this list to only the entries in both files, pipe the output of the above command into uniq

```
$ join file1_t.txt file2_t.txt | uniq
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to `sort` before you `join`.

```
$ cat a.in
TERYUFV00000010753
TERYUFV00000009526
$ cat b.in
TERYUFV00000009526 refids_739_known_8/10_target
TERYUFV00000018907 refids_12023_known_21/22_target
TERYUFV00000010753 refids_11775_known_1/1_target
$ join a.in b.in
$ join <(sort a.in) <(sort b.in)
TERYUFV00000009526 refids_739_known_8/10_target
TERYUFV00000010753 refids_11775_known_1/1_target
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your files are sorted:

```
comm -12 file1 file2
```

Comment: Did you test your method before posting it here? It doesn't work for this question. comm compares the two sorted files by the entire line. So, a line of "TERYUFV00000010753" in file1 is different from a line of "TERYUFV00000010753 refids_11775_known_1/1_target" in file2.

Answer (score 1):

Does the following line work?

```
grep -iw -f file1.txt file2.txt
```

If the files were uploaded to the server from a Windows client, maybe you should run the dos2unix first.

```
dos2unix file1.txt file2.txt
```

If the above commands do not work, you can try the following lines to see whether there are extra nonprinting characters at the beginning or end of the lines in file1.txt. The extra nonprinting characters in items of file1.txt may lead to the failure of grep from file2.txt.

```
cat -v file1.txt
sed -n -l file1.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve this problem using `AWK`:

```
NR == FNR {
    line[$1];
    next;
}
$1 in line {
    print $0;
}
```

As an one liner:

`awk 'NR == FNR {line[$1]; next;} $1 in line' file1.txt file2.txt`

Be sure to store in memory the smaller file, that is, put it as the first argument of the one liner.